# How to center the options in select menu which are created dynamically in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, select, mobile, center

I have added options for select menu dynamically. But i want the options to be aligned center in the menu and not in the left. Please help.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="b">
<h1>My Page</h1>
<select id="selectMenu">
</select>
```

JS:

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    $('#selectMenu').append("<option value="i+">Option "+i+"</option>");
}
```

Comment: please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of CSS, look at this :

http://jsfiddle.net/hYLfG/

```
select {
  text-align : center;
}
```

OR style inline :

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="b">
<h1>My Page</h1>
<select id="selectMenu" style="text-align:center;">
</select>
```

Comment: I want the options to be aligned in center.. Giving styling for option is not working

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: text-align on a select is not currently cross-browser. It works with firefox but not with chrome, for example